# Зачем нужен Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Повсеместное использование hibernate начинает подбешивать. Я не против но то что я наблюдаю ставит под сомнение использование hibernate в java приложениях.

1. Все современные базы данных умеют работать в режиме in-memory. Незачем напрягать одну jvm если есть специальный механизм правильно работающий с данными.
2. Никто, повторюсь никто, из разработчиков использующих hibernete не проводит исследование и конфигурирование памяти jvm и политики GC при использовании hibernete. А надо.
3. По каким-то неведомым для меня причинам разработчики не используют, не конфигурируют пул соединений, и потом заявляют, что все очень медленно. (доверив конфигурации по умолчанию)
4. Почему-то у всех проблема с распределенными базами данных, источниками данных, и по этому hibernete -это вроде к панацея для работы с распределенными источниками (лишь редкие единицы слышали про двухфазный коммит)
5. Чаще всего используется слепой метод генерации таблиц данных. Т.е. разработчик пишет новый POJO потом на основании это объекта генерируется еще одна табличка в базе и так продолжается пока разработчик не устанет генерировать классы. Ни одна база не будет нормализована при таком подходе. Я видел разработчиков по 10 раз создающих классы: Date,Dates,дата,Дата и хотя это одна и таже сущность разработчику проще нагененрировать еще один класс, чем обратиться к базе данных. Не дай бог,  если  в  приложении  нужны справочники (НСИ).  В этом случае   разработчик  прост о запихивает  весь  справочник  в память JVM  используя  hibernate как этого делать  не стоит.
6. Все забыли про хранимые процедуры и пользовательские функции существующие в современных база данных, а с помощью столь примитивных механизмом можно сделать много чего полезного БЕЗ НАГРУЗКИ НА JVM приложения.
7. Разработчики пренебрегают принципом -"делай как можно проще" и используя hibernete пытаются создать многопоточные приложения с поддержкой различных уровней транзакциооности и снова игнорируя управление памятью JVM. (Проще добавить памяти чем
   создавать приложение без hibernete).

К чему я все это. Я уже высказался об отвратительном Springe (мне сразу сняли несколько сотен баллов), но теперь по крайней мере у нас в компании возможность использования spring только после десятка согласований. Я к тому, что каким бы хорошим не был фраймворк, нельзя следовать дикой моде и вклячивать повсеместно без раздумий то, что нравиться разработчика - по причине модности.
В чем я не прав в отношениях с hibernate?

Comment: Любопытно. А по п.2 и 3 можно какие-нибудь ссылки на почитать? По всему остальному: в 90% случаев главное - быстрее. Что хибер и позволяет сделать. Не успел реализовать функционал - тебя опередили и ты не нужен. Быстрее + большинство вопросов можно решить добавлением ресурсов железа. Это опять-таки быстрее и проще, чем fine-tuning ПО. Имхо, естественно. Требования по супер-производительности или супер-нагруженности не в счет.

Comment: не прав по 2 пунктам: 1)криворукие разработчики почему-то загнали в минус хибернейт)) хибернейт - не золотой молоток, а любая технология либо паттерн, использованный криво, превращается в антипаттерн / антитехнологию. 2)вы не учитываете бизнес. а кто за девушку платит, то ее и танцует. выживает то, что быстрее в разработке, а, следовательно, дешевле для бизнеса. обескровленная доменная модель быстрее в разработке, поэтому спринг и ему подобные. где вы сейчас видели rich модель? и не важно, что это не про ооп. мы пишем код за деньги и бизнес диктует свои правила)) тоже самое с хибернейтом

Comment: Stackoverflow плохой ресурс для подобных "вопросов", такое нужно вбрасывать на форумах разработчиков, чтоб "дискутировать", долго и продолжительно :)

Comment: Да спасибо.  Пойду на сайт Hibernete. Кину в  них  грязным тапком.:-)

Answer (score 7):

Это конечно наброс и холивар, но я отвечу :)

> Ни одна база не будет нормализована при таком подходе.

3-я нормальная форма всегда получается естественным образом :)
Бывает что наоборот, сознательно избегают нормализации для оптимизации в каких-то узких случаях (например для извлечения древовидных структур из реляционной базы), но уже не новички.

> Чаще всего используется слепой метод генерации таблиц данных.

Зависит от проектов надо которым ты работал. Бывает что программа появляется одновременно с базой и структура базы формируется параллельно с backend (как в startup-ах на коленке), в этом случае можно нагенерировать таблицы из POJO. А когда проект уже работает, обслуживает пользователей, их данные уже нельзя потерять, то люди занимаются базой по серьезному и накатывают изменения как положено.

> Все забыли про хранимые процедуры и пользовательские функции существующие в современных база данных, а с помощью столь примитивных механизмом можно сделать много чего полезного БЕЗ НАГРУЗКИ НА JVM приложения.

Ничего против них не имею, использую, но с хранимыми процедурами сразу возникает несколько проблем: 1. Версионирование 2. Усложнение развертывания приложения 3. Сложный дебагинг.

А корень проблемы в том, что при использовании хранимых процедур у нас бизенс-логика размазана сразу в нескольких местах, часть будет в backend, а другая часть в хранимых процедурах. Причем с усложнением приложения будет куча хранимых процедур которые будут зависеть от работы друг-друга. В общем новому разработчику уже не скажешь "читай код", все будет несколько сложнее, появятся тайные знания у нескольких коренных разрабов которые будут точно знать в какой последовательности какие хранимки должны быть вызваны чтоб таблица Х пришла в нужную кондицию.

> Никто, повторюсь никто, из разработчиков использующих hibernete не проводит исследование и конфигурирование памяти jvm и политики GC при использовании hibernete.

Понятия не имею о чем ты. Если есть подозрение на утечку памяти то запускаешь VisualVM и смотришь что и где. Работал в энтерпрайзах и не сталкивался с проблемами конкретно в Hibernate.

> Все современные базы данных умеют работать в режиме in-memory. Незачем напрягать одну jvm если есть специальный механизм правильно работающий с данными.

Вообще ОРМ не для in-memory оптимизаций выбирают, а чтоб облегчить себе работу с данными из кода, ОРМ позволяет абстрагироваться от таблиц и работать сразу с объектами. Если бы не ORM то люди бы до сих пор писали себе прото-фреймворки по патернам из книг того же Мартина нашего Фаулера, делали бы свои доморощенные реализации Active Recrod и Data Mapper, вот Hibernate ORM это как раз Data Mapper на стероидах.

> не используют, не конфигурируют пул соединений,

Если говорить про Java, то самый раскрученный в мире Java фреймворк это Spring, там из коробки доступен HikariCP и вроде по бенчмаркам он один из самых быстрых. Что там конфигурировать? Я знаю только что если запрос быстрой, но backend данные вытаскивает медленно то нужно увеличить fetch size :)

> Проще добавить памяти чем создавать приложение без hibernete

Мне один Project Manager прямо так и сказал - время одного дня работы разработчиков дороже чем стоимость планки памяти. Оптимизациями занимаются только когда есть проблема которую нельзя решить вертикальным масштабированием, или цена такого масштабирования уже больше зарплаты разработчика.

Answer (score 6):

Ну вот я не шарю в hibernate, но умею гуглить.

Открываем [доку](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/quickstart/html_single/#preface), читаем что такое hibernate

> Hibernate is an Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) solution for Java environments.

То есть по сути это просто ORM для Java

В чем цель этой ORM?

> Hibernate’s design goal is to relieve the developer from 95% of common data persistence-related programming tasks by eliminating the need for manual, hand-crafted data processing using SQL and JDBC.

Быстрее разработка, чтобы уменьшить количество ручного труда. Что еще оно может?

> Hibernate can certainly help you to remove or encapsulate vendor-specific SQL code and streamlines the common task of translating result sets from a tabular representation to a graph of objects.

Ну вот про инкапсуляцию конкретной БД пишут, что мол один код, как я понял, будет на разных БД работать.

Все остальные фичи, всякие кеши и прочие вещи в hibernate, получается, не являются сутью hibernate или его презназначением, а больше просто как доп фичи.

Что вы обсуждаете:

1. Какие то проблемы с памятью, не связанные ни с hiberhate, ни с какой-либо другой ORM.
2. Криворукие разрабы
3. Криворукие разрабы
4. `hibernete -это вроде к панацея для работы с распределенными источниками` не нашел такого в доке
5. Оспариваете Code-First подход, это точно претензия к hibernate?
6. Древний спор: хранимки против логики в коде, казалось бы причем тут hibernate?
7. Криворукие разрабы

То есть, по сути, ваши претензии то не к hibernate и не имеют ничего с ним общего. Каждый инструмент строится для конкретной цели, и если разрабы берут молоток, но вместо забивания гвоздей бьют им друг друга по голове - это не проблема молотка.

Comment: Попробую изложить свою мысль по другому. Hibernet жрет память JVM  мегабайтами,  или даже  гигабайтами, что  совсем  не хорошо для JVM и GC. И главное, разработчик не озадачивается проблемой структуры данных, он  просто генерирует  классы на скорость.  Насчет  быстроты разработки  то это если не знать  JDBC ( я думаю  этомаркетинговый ход ).  Connection pool  создаваемый  Hibernete   се равно требует  настройки ,  не  не использования по умолчанию,  но разработчики используют по умолчанию.  Ну а насчет работать с разными базами данных. Ну даже  сказать  нечего.. это  просто замануха

Comment: @Труфальдино ну так я и говорю, у вас получаются претензии к криворуким разрабам, а не к конкретной либе. Надо понимать, что подобные ORM - это вообще не про память и не про скорость работы, это про удобсво и скорость разработки (так называемый time to market). Если хотите супер скоростную работу - то это, похоже, не сюда. Вы же не сравниваете круизный лайнер и скоростной катер. Но это я как обыватель говорю, сам этой либой не пользовался, но судя по фичам это многопалубный лайнер и он явно не для гонок.

Comment: Спасибо. Тут может быть вы правы.  Любое использование ПО ,  любого ПО,  сязано  с пряморукостью  разработчика. И увы. Не  все разработчики пряморуки.